# How to display posts with a certain tag

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm really struggling at what I am sure is a simple problem. I cannot seem to get the posts which fall under a certain tag to display on that tags page ie: (/tag/blog/) with blog being the Tag.

So far following the [Official Tag Templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Tag_Templates) page on Wordpress I still cannot seem to get it working.

I do not need a heirarchy so tag.php works fine. Using `single_tag_title()` it does correctly display the tag at the top of the page.

The rest of the [Official Tag Templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Tag_Templates) does not really give much more detail on wether or not I can use the default Loop or a custom one. I have tried with the custom one as shown below but that does not work. (I've kept it down to the minimum not currently worried about styling.)

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<p>Tag: <?php single_tag_title(); ?></p>
<div class="container">
    <div id="content" class="clearfix row">
        <div id="main" class="col col-lg-8 clearfix blog-page-padding" role="main">
            <?php 
                if ( have_posts() ) :
                    while ( have_posts() ) :
                        the_title();
                    endwhile; // end while
                endif; // end if
            ?>
        </div> <!-- end #main -->
    <?php get_sidebar('blog'); // Blog ?>
    </div> <!-- end #content -->
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

So this code currently does display the title of the Tag but not the title of the posts which I am trying to get out.

**To wrap the question up**. "How do I display the posts which fall under a certain tag."

Comment: Are these default tags, or are you using a custom taxonomy as tags

Comment: Default Tags. Thanks

Comment: Have you switched to one of the bundled themes. Wordpress V4 was released today, have you upgraded. Don't you have any code that restrict access and info from certain user roles, or users not logged in

Comment: No i havent updated. I was thinking could it be that the tag is used across 2 custom post types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I had to use a WP Query loop to bring them in due to being custom post types.

```
<?php if ( is_tag() ) {$term_id = get_query_var('tag_id'); $taxonomy = 'post_tag'; $args ='include=' . $term_id; $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, $args );} ?>
            <!-- This gets the tags slug  -->

<?php $query = new WP_Query(array( "post_type" => array('blog', 'portfolio'), "tag" => $terms[0]->slug   ) ); while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>

        <?php the_title(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: You should add **"details"** like that in you next posts. Also, you could use the `pre_get_posts` action

Answer (score 0):

You're not telling the loop to look for that particular tag anywhere...all you're doing is displaying the current selected tag at the top of the page. Add a PHP `if` statement into your loop to grab the posts with that tag:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>     // Get the header

<p>Tag: <?php single_tag_title(); ?></p>     // Display the tag name

<div class="container">
    <div id="content" class="clearfix row">
        <div id="main" class="col col-lg-8 clearfix blog-page-padding" role="main">


            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?> // Start your loop

                    <?php if(tag_slug( ' THE SLUG ' ) ) : ?> // Look for the tag
                           // Post HTML stuff
                    <?php endif; ?>

                <?php endwhile; endif ?> // finish the loop

        </div> <!-- end #main -->
    <?php get_sidebar('blog'); // Blog ?>
    </div> <!-- end #content -->
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

[This page from the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) has examples of how to grab categories and tags.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've tried using your tag and replacing THE SLUG with the tag in question but it does not seem to want to work. Is there anything you would like me to test to see why?

Comment: You included the post PHP in the `if` loop, correct? I didn't show it in the sample above, so add `<?php the_content(); ?> to see if that works.

Comment: Replacing // Post HTML stuff with that? Yeah I did but it didn't post anything. Which makes me think it still cannot locate the posts.

Comment: I was thinking could it be that the tag is used across 2 custom post types?

Answer (score 0):

You just need the `the_post()` function, you have to call it inside the while, and it should be the first function you call, as it loads the template tags.

```
<?php 
                if ( have_posts() ) :
                    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                        the_title();
                    endwhile; // end while
                endif; // end if
            ?>
```

if the tags is just used in custom post types you should add something like this to you functions.php:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_function' );

function custom_function($query){
  if(! is_admin()){
    if(is_tag()){
        $query->set('post_type', array('your_post_type', 'your_other_post_type', 'post'));
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Although I am afraid that did not work.

Comment: Isn't your tag empty? Try to turn on debugging. You don't have any custom queries or filters?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No the tag does have some posts. There is not custom queries or filters on that page. I'm not too sure how to use debugging.

Comment: If you aren't in production you can do it simply by adding this line to wp-config.php `define('WP_DEBUG', true);`

Comment: Yeah I can try that I was also thinking could it be that the tag is used across 2 custom post types?

Comment: @jackdh, I updated the answer. Are you using the tag just in custom post types?